# How do I create a new item for a has_and_belongs_to_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have models set up such that:

**Item** has_and_belongs_to_many **BatchTicket**

**How can I define @batch_ticket in the BatchTicket controller for new batch ticket creation?**
This doesn't work:

```
class BatchTicketsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @batch_ticket = item.batch_tickets.build
  end
end
```

I'm not sure how to correctly identify 'item'. There is nothing in the params[]. I've put the id in the 'li' seen below.

Code to try to create a new BatchTicket (lists correctly):

```
<h4>New Orders</h4>
<ul>
    <% @items_to_plan.each do |item| %>
        <li id="<%= item.id %>"><%= item.item_code %> <%= link_to "new", new_batch_ticket_path(item) %> | 
        <%= link_to "cmb", '#' %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
undefined local variable or method `item' for #<BatchTicketsController:0x007ff1bd48f808>
```

Comment: create item object first using item.find(params[:id])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing `item` as an argument to `new_batch_ticket_path`, you've implicitly passed `item_id` to your controller via `params[:item_id]`. Using that, you can do a lookup of the respective `Item` object you need:

Presuming that you're using RESTful routes, your `new_batch_ticket_path` is not expecting to receive any arguments. As such, you need to explicitly declare whatever you're passing in as a GET variable. In this case, you should pass `item.id` as `item_id`:

```
<%= link_to "new", new_batch_ticket_path(:item_id => item.id) %>

# app/controllers/batch_tickets_controller.rb
def new
    if params[:item_id]
        item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
        @batch_ticket = item.batch_tickets.build
    else
        @batch_ticket = BatchTicket.create
    end
end
```

Notice the if-else conditional? You need that in order to handle instances where the new action is called *without* passing a GET `item_id` variable. Remember that your route is not expecting to be passed any arguments, so you'll need to handle both instances when a variable is passed, and also when one isn't.